# Is it possible to outsource some tasks of thesis writing? How and what kind of tasks?

Tags: thesis, writing, service-activities

I think that thesis writing is a big project which can be divided into several small-scale tasks. The contribution of the thesis must be done with student himself/herself, but other tasks such as figure preparation, writing in LaTex, editing, training, advising, etc. can be outsourced. Am I right?
In your opinion what kind of tasks can be outsourced and how?

Comment: I would definitely hesitate to EVER use the word "illegal" in describing an issue of this nature.  No court of law ever is going to be even the slightest bit interested in the "legality" of your ghostwriting a thesis.  By writing someone else's thesis you might have committed a "fraud" on the institution...but strictly speaking that's not ILLEGAL, but rather "Anti-contractual."

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the most ethical and legal answer to someone who is unethically and illegally asks others for writing his thesis (some parts or the whole) in any form (from doing research to typesetting and etc.) is a big **NO**!

By hearing **NO**!s from others, that person will understand that he is the only person who is responsible in writing his academic manuscript and he has social responsibility as a student to do his own research.

Thesis research is not something like procurement or construction project to be outsourced.

Help such person and help your society by saying **NO** to such requests!

Comment: Suggestion: change "his" to "his or her" and "he" to "he or she"?

Comment: I changed the question to not be duplicate

Comment: *"... to typesetting"*. I learned English at a much younger age, than my father, thus I have a much better command of it. He frequently asks me to check for typos, grammatical errors, etc, in papers, he's preparing for submission (I obviously do not expect to be acknowledged in any way in the paper). Is that unethical? If not, why is a thesis different, and where should the line be drawn (and why specifically there)?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP you say your father *frequently asks you to check for typos [...]*; he neither outsources his typesetting to you, nor pays somebody else to write his thesis for him (as described in questions). Asking questions is appreciated in either academic or other situations; but paying money to do research duties is not really acceptable anywhere.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Imagine somebody who received some funding or scholarships, and pays some less money to other people to do the research for him, some other people to write papers for him and some other to typeset his texts and draw graphs! After all, he may save some money from that amount he received as his scholarships besides to a PhD degree which he perfectly managed other people to do it for him. This is absolutely not acceptable in academic context. Research and university is not a place for such people to outsource their academic duties. Students are responsible for their own research duties.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Let me be blunter then. How is LaTeX wizardry relevant to *research*? If someone does not know and can't be bothered to learn LaTeX, or good typesetting skills in general, what is unethical about paying someone to do the tedium for them? Allow me also to point out, that the OP explicitly excludes *research* work from the question. Also let me note, that re: typesetting, many journals typeset the article for you anyway, while the authors are required to submit in a draft format without prettifying the layout.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I am, e.g. thinking of a situation, where the lazy student would honestly write up his thesis in a .txt file (or otherwise convey the text to the typesetter), supply him with a scan of handwritten equations and say "make this pretty in LaTeX" for me. Now admittedly, this student will be a bad scientific employee, because employees are far more efficient, when they can do these tasks themselves, but I cannot see, why his *degree in science (not typesetting)* would be undeserved.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Let me give an example, do you know any car driver who does not know how to use horn and consequently asks someone else to do it for him? Do you call such person a qualified driver? I do not think he is qualified as a driver at all. The same applies here. Being accepted as a student and wining a scholarship means that the person has some minimum skills. He has minimum capabilities in studying and doing research, knowing English and computer skills. If he lacks some skills, he should try to learn, or pay for some classes to learn that skill, not to pay somebody else to do it for him.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent In that case we have to agree to disagree, as the car example is, IMO, not equivalent at all. Obtaining a driver's license *requires* knowledge of, among other things, sounding the horn. Knowledge of LaTeX is not yet common on the list of requirements for research positions (not to mention, that many journals accept Word). Finally, and most importantly, things such as typesetting are simply not enough to merit co-authorship. Therefore, while I agree, that this practice makes the outsourcer a poor *employee*, it does not take from the value of *his research*.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I still cannot agree with you, because not having skills in typesetting or LaTeX is not a good reason for the student to outsource his duties. Minimum requirement for a student is the ability to learn new things, and typesetting his own thesis and drawing its figures (as described in the question) are the easiest skills to be learnt if the student does not know them. Nobody expects a student to typeset his thesis or papers texts in a week (because he is not having a typesetting career), but he can do typesetting his texts in a longer period of time (for instance one month).

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent 50 years ago, typists were part of the staff at some institutes to type up papers from scientists' handwritten notes. LaTeX came as a huge step forward in automating the typesetting. I can envision a future, where a more advanced software will typeset a wall of text from notepad properly without any `\environments{}` input by the user. Universities will likely purchase campus-wide licenses for this software, and suddenly everyone will be outsourcing their typesetting *at the expense of the university*, again.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent [Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_typist), explicitly states *"... they would have typed up dissertations..."*

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I am not neglecting typists' specialty, but we are not living in 50 years ago. Now, students have personal computers which give them tools for their research, from searching data and programming, reading papers and books and etc to typing their publications. I think, students should have minimum skill of typing their thesis and papers in a simple notepad document. Even they have not knowledge to work with LaTeX, they should be able to type their documents in a simple notepad page. This skill, at least, does not need to be outsourced.